# Finding limit points for these sets

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Here's my resoning for finding limit points for some sets. Could you guys read it and see if it's all good? <3

$$\{(x,y)\mid \ x^2+y^2<1\}$$
For this set, its kinda simple to see that every point can be a limit point, because every open ball with center in a point of this set, will have another point diferente from the center.

$$\{(x,1)\mid x=\frac{1}{N}, n\in \mathbb N\}$$

Besides having some holes (not the complete real line), given a point of this set, I can always construct an open ball, and then I try the points $\frac{1}{10}, \frac{1}{100}\cdots \frac{1}{1000000000}$ until I find one that is inside the ball. So every point of this set is a limit point.

$$\{(x,y)\mid x,y\in \mathbb Q\}$$

Same reasoning as before, but now in two dimensions. Would be nice to have a proof. Can somebody help me?

$$\{(x,y)\mid x,y\in \mathbb N\}$$

Here I can't always draw an open ball that contains another point except the one in the center, because I'm working with the integers. If I construct a ball with radius $\frac{1}{2}$ then no onter point is in it.

$$\{(x,y)\mid x=1, 1<y<2\}$$

Every point of this set is a limit point, by the same reasons...

Comment: You should explicitly give an answer (i.e. the set of limit points) for each of those sets. Otherwise, it is hard to tell if you are correct or not. Also, keep in mind that a limit point of a set doesn't necessarily have to be in the set.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 so the limit points of the first set is, in fact $\{(x,y)| \ x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I am assuming that given a set $S \subset R^2$, we are looking for limit points of $S$ that are in $R^2$, not just in $S.$

I don't follow your arguments. Take for example the second question. It is not clear what you mean when you say, `given a point of this set, I can always construct an open ball, and then I try the points $1/10,1/100⋯1/1000000000$ until I find one that is inside the ball.`

In fact, none of the points in the set in the second example (let's call that set $S$) are limit points of that set. This is because for any point $x$ in that set, I can find an open ball in $R^2$ whose intersection with $S$ is $\{x\}$. (Prove this!) But the point $(0,1)$ is a limit point of that set.

A hint for the third question: Any open interval in $R^1$ contains rational points. This gives a hint for the fourth question: there are open intervals in $R^1$ that do not contain any integer points. You would have to extend these claims to similar statements about open balls in $R^2$.

Comment: In the second paragraph shouldn't it be the point $(0, 1)$ instead of the point $(1,1)$?

Comment: Yes, thanks. It is fixed.

Comment: In the second question, I was saying that, given a point of the set, no matter how tiny the ball is, I can Always find a point inside the ball, that is rational.

Comment: @user166793 could you help me in the second question? Can't understand the reason of why $(0,1)$ is the limit point, and why the others aren't.

Comment: Here is an example. The point $(1/2,1)$ is not a limit point of that set. The reason is that the closest elements to that point in that set are $(1/3,1)$ and $(1/4,1)$. The distance from $(1/2,1)$ to $(1/3,1)$ is 1/6 and the distance from $(1/2,1)$ to $(1/4,1)$ is 1/4. So the open ball in $R^2$ of radius 1/6 (or less) centered at $(1/2,1)$ contains no points in that set other than $(1/2,1)$. This is why the point $(1/2,1)$ is not a limit point. It might help to draw a picture. The same reasoning applies to the other points. But, $(0,1)$ is different and you should think about why.

Comment: @user166793 shouldn't $(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{1000000},1)$ be a point close to $(\frac{1}{2},1)$, in the form $(\frac{1}{N},1)$?

Comment: The number $\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{10^6}$ is not in the form $\tfrac{1}{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can find easily the limit points in **complex plane** or in $\Bbb R^2$ Plane,  as we find in case of Real line **$\Bbb R$**.

I think the set set of limit points of set **$\{(x,y)|x,y \in \Bbb N\}$**  is empty set $\emptyset$ and hence it is closed set.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S = \{ (x,y): x^2 + y^2 < 1 \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

---

Firstly, let me define a slightly stronger term - **Accumulation Point**

> A point $x$ is an accumulation point of a subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}^p$ if and only if every reduced neighborhood of $x$ has a nonempty intersection with $A$, that it, for every $r>0$ we have $B'(x,r)\cap A \neq \emptyset$.

We will denote the set of accumulation points of $S$ by $S'$.

Accumulation points are somewhat "stronger" than limit points, however we know that if a point is an accumulation point, the point is also a limit point. (The converse is not necessarily true).

---

So now, consider the following sketch of our region $S$.

[image]

Now, consider any arbitrary point $x \in S$ - I have drawn a few examples in the following sketch. Clearly for every $x \in S$ we have that for every $r>0$, $B'(x,r)\cap A \neq \emptyset$. Hence $S \subset S'$.

[image]

Now let us consider the boundary, that is, the set $S_b = \{ (x,y) | x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$

[image]

Clearly for every $x \in S_b$ we have that $x \in S'$ since for every $r>0$, $B'(x,r)\cap A \neq \emptyset$. Thus $S_b \subset S' $

Now, let us lasty consider and point $x \in \{ (x,y): x^2 + y^2 > 1 \}$

[image]

For every $x \in \{ (x,y): x^2 + y^2 > 1 \}$ there exists an $r>0$ such that $B'(x,r) \cap A = \emptyset$. Thus $\{ (x,y): x^2 + y^2 > 1 \} \not\subset S'$.

From the above we may deduce that $S' = S\cup S_b = \{ (x,y): x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \}$.

And thus we also have that $\{ (x,y): x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \}$ are limit points of $S$.